# Extracting text from json within <script> tag when multiple jsons are present

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the Rating from https://www.truthorfiction.com/are-americans-annually-healthcare-undocumented/ in order to extract the "ratingValue" and "alternateName" fields from the HTML code:

```
<script type=application/ld+json>{
"@context": "http://schema.org",
"@type": "ClaimReview",
"datePublished": "2019-01-03 ",
"url": "https://www.truthorfiction.com/are-americans-annually-healthcare-undocumented/",
"author": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "url": "https://www.truthorfiction.com/",
    "image": "https://dn.truthorfiction.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/25032229/truth-or-fiction-logo-tagline.png",
    "sameAs": "https://twitter.com/whatstruecom"
},
"claimReviewed": "More Americans die every year from a lack of affordable healthcare than by terrorism or at the hands of undocumented immigrants.",
"reviewRating": {
    "@type": "Rating",
    "ratingValue": -1,
    "worstRating":-1,
    "bestRating": -1,
    "alternateName": "True"
},
    "itemReviewed": {
    "@type": "CreativeWork",
    "author": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "Person",
        "jobTitle": "",
        "image": "",
        "sameAs": [
            ""
        ]
    },
    "datePublished": "",
    "name": ""
}
}</script>
```

I have tried to do that using the following code:

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

slink = 'https://www.truthorfiction.com/are-americans-annually-healthcare-undocumented/'
response = http.request('GET', slink)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data)
tmp = json.loads(soup.find('script', type='application/ld+json').text)
```

However, tmp instead shows a dictionary of the 'application/ld+json' item from the bit preceding the ratings that I would like to extract, and I was wondering how to cycle or loop to the relevant part of the script where the ratings are stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it has 2 `<script type=application/ld+json>` you can select second index from `find_all()`

```
tmp = json.loads(soup.find_all('script', type='application/ld+json')[1].text)
```

or loop and search if it contains the string

```
tmp = None
for ldjson in soup.find_all('script', type='application/ld+json'):
    if 'ratingValue' in ldjson.text:
        tmp = json.loads(ldjson.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the element using the keys.

```
rating_value = tmp['reviewRating']['ratingValue'] # -1
alternate_name = tmp['reviewRating']['alternateName'] # 'True'
```

or

```
review_rating = tmp['reviewRating']
rating_value = review_rating['ratingValue'] # -1
alternate_name = review_rating['alternateName'] # 'True'
```

Comment: The problem I have is that the first json that soup.find locates is assigned to tmp instead of the json where rating_value and alternate_name are found, and I'm not sure how to load the relevant json into tmp. `KeyError: 'reviewRating`

Comment: You can use the `find_all()` method and afterwards iterate through the collection of tags: `all_scripts = soup.find_all('script')`.